# How to remove characters from a list.

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list output:

> ['Go497f9te(40RAAC34)\n','G0THDU433(40RAAC33)\n']

and I want to clean it up in order to output:

> [40RAAC34,40RAAC33]

Comment: `[re.findall(r'\(([^\)]+)\)', s) for s in output]`

Comment: Ok, and your question is...? What was your attempt and how did it not work as intended?

Comment: If you use re.findall, you will need to import re

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a string:

```
'hello (world)'
```

and want the text between the brackets, you can either use a regex:

```
import re
re.findall('\((.*?)\)', s)[0]
#'world'
```

or, if you are sure that there is only one set of brackets (i.e. no leading `)` chars) then you can just use slicing:

```
s[s.index('(')+1:s.index(')')]
#'world'
```

---

So then you just need to throw this into a list-comprehension or similar.

```
l = ['Go497f9te(40RAAC34)\n','G0THDU433(40RAAC33)\n']
[s[s.index('(')+1:s.index(')')] for s in l]
#['40RAAC34', '40RAAC33']
```

Comment: No problem, please accept!